# Searching records between two date columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with below format

```
--------------------------------------------------------
type   |   requirements   |   from       |     to      |
--------------------------------------------------------
 A          23               2012-12-12      2012-12-24|
--------------------------------------------------------
B           22               2012-12-10      2013-01-14|
--------------------------------------------------------
C           20               2013-11-18      2012-12-10|
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Now when I search the total requirements for a date 2010-12-23. I should get

```
----------------------------
  type   |   requirements   |
  ---------------------------
    A          23           |
  ---------------------------
    B           22          |
-----------------------------
```

What is the query to get this result? I searched a lot but couldn't find any hint. Please help me.

Comment: what exactly you want??? i mean your question seems bit weird... as you want to find total requirements using from date and to date... that are already stored in table then why dont you just call select statement with colums type and requirements??

Comment: Dont get confused Rony, I just want the query eggyal posted.

Comment: exactly what i was saying buddy.... just check that...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that by `'2010-12-23'` you meant `'2012-12-23'`, you can filter using MySQL's [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) comparison operator:

```
SELECT `type`, `requirements`
FROM   `my_table`
WHERE  '2012-12-23' BETWEEN `from` AND `to`
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6833f/5/0).

Comment: Thank you very much eggyal. I lack the very basic SQL knowledge. Thank you very much. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE "from" > "2010-12-23" AND "to" < "2010-12-23"
```

?

If you want to include the two dates you could use >= and <= or also use BETWEEN like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE "2010-12-23" BETWEEN "from" AND "to"
```

Just FYI, the names "from" and "to" are not ideal as column names, but I guess you just posted it as example.

Comment: Cool. Thank you very much andreas for giving me a good insight.